# How to take data from multiple BLE devices into a central device simultaneously?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, publish-subscriber

Firstly, I am very beginner in BLE domain. I have very little knowledge about it.

I have [Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2829) module.

I want to do a project where multiple BLE peripheral devices connected with a central BLE device(Andriod phone). Each peripheral device collecting data from the different sensors, like first peripheral interfacing with humidity sensor second peripheral device interfacing with a light sensor so on..

I need to collect data from all peripheral devices into my central device. It will be best if I can collect the data from different peripherals simultaneously. If it is not possible to collect the data simultaneously then what procedure I should follow that it seems that data collection going on a simultaneous manner.

My question is how to achieve my objective. What is the way and which algorithm I need to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like an obvious case for MQTT ? Failing that, roll your own and use a CRUD HTTP(s) RESTful API to a server on your Android

Comment: Hi, @Mawg I didn't get you clearly. Can you please explain it bit more.

Comment: Personally, I would use [MQTT](http://mqtt.org) If you don't want to, you can just use HTTP GET or PUT  e.g `http:my_server.com/write_value.php?value=XX`

Comment: @Mawg, nrf51 does not support wifi.

Comment: @Prayuktibid, you can also put your BLE devices on indirect advertising. That way you can scan them with your phone and get data without a connection. Things go waay easier like this.

Comment: @MarcoTulioSouza Lets assume a case when central device talking with a peripheral device, The other peripheral device has to send to an important data with the highest priority how to handle this situation?